# Tfs Work Item search not return for contains

Tags: tfs

sql "Select FROM WorkItem CONTAINS "Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root" not find result in

Action ended 11:12:05: CatalogFolderCheck. Return value 1.

Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root. Please specify a folder.

[11:12:05:099]: Product: Backup Catalog -- Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root. Please specify a folder.

But find if search "Please specify a folder".

any idea why it could be?
appreciated for help

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com/xxx) or  Azure DevOps Server (on-premise TFS)? How did you run "Tfs Work Item search", could you please share your detailed steps, screenshot added will be better?

Comment: Hello, CeceDong-MSFT Thank you for reply. doing the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=azure-devops . WIQL example: SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title] 
   FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.Description] CONTAINS 'Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root.'

Comment: i wonder why it fails to find workItem by line  'Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root.' but works ok if query is SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.Description] CONTAINS 'Please specify a folder.'

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following WIQL:

```
select [System.Id], [System.Title] from WorkItems where [System.Description] contains words 'Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root'
```

I've tried adding your description in two tasks on my side, check screenshot below:

[image]

And then run query in query editor, it could get a successful result:

[image]

Comment: same thing. i quess that it could be because of duplicate line in description. 'Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root'. but can't verify that

Comment: Could you show us what exact in your Description field?

Comment: <div><br></div><div></div><div><div>[03:46:21:989]: Adding property.</div><div>******&nbsp; Checking folder...</div><div>Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root. Please specify a folder.</div><div>[03:46:21:989]: Product: Backup Catalog -- Catalog cannot be placed in a volume root. Please specify a folder.</div></div><div><br></div><div></div><div></div><div><br></div>

Comment: I've tested your description on my side, and still got a successful result. Check my update to see whether you can get the same result.

Comment: Thank you for follow up. I will try again in my environment and return.